# Retrieving Client Credentials grant token returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm setting up Laravel Passport's Client Grant and using Guzzle to retrieve a token, but I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error.

I created the client using: `php artisan passport:client --client`.
The client generated is:

```
Client ID: 1
Client secret: NmJsEVFClXVqWJuQnZTWA3bnZEVZ0KaC13anHZt1
```

I saved these in my .env file and ran the command

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Here's my code:

```
        $url = 'http://hub.local/oauth/token';

        $client_secret = env('CLIENT_SECRET');
        $client_id = env('CLIENT_ID');
        $client = new Client();

        try {
            $response = $client->post($url, [
                'json' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
                    'client_id' => $client_id,
                    'client_secret' => $client_secret,
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ]);
            return $response;
        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            dd($e);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
```

And the resulting error message:

```
ClientException {#660 ▼
  -request: Request {#649 ▶}
  -response: Response {#657 ▶}
  -handlerContext: []
  #message: """
    Client error: `POST http://hub.local/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
    {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed","message":"Client authentication failed"}
    """
  #code: 401
  #file: "C:\repos\client\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php"
  #line: 113
```

When I try the request using the same parameters and values in Insomnia, the request works.
Seems I can't post images yet.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5haB.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1eTs.jpg

I'm using Laravel 5.8.12, Guzzle 6.3.3 and Passport 7.2.2.
What am I missing?

Comment: Please never post passwords or API tokens (client secrets) here!

Comment: @PowerStat thanks for the heads-up. I know the danger with publishing auth credentials, but this is a local instance for testing and I wanted to head off any concerns as to whether I was using the correct client secret in the request. In reading the other questions related to this topic, that was an error in some cases, so this was just me showing in advance that that's not a possible error source for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Update: The problem only occurred when I was running the ( Laravel) client and server instances on the same local xampp server. I separated them to run on their own individual xampp instances and the authentication worked without issue. What had confused me while testing solely locally was that the request worked with Insomnia, but not the browser. I'm assuming that the "machine to machine" part of this client grant was seeing my client + server sharing the same xampp instance as something unrecognized. In any event, there's no actual problem. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

in laravel doc there is an example like this :

```
Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://your-app.com/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => 'client-id',
            'client_secret' => 'client-secret',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/callback',
            'code' => $request->code,
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

when I tested this one with my info I changed to some thing like this :

```
Route::get('/users/login', function (Request $request) {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://payment.devenv/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 2,
            'client_secret' => 'z8YWlJeaW0d7o7SFyPLISUxYOcO5CxjGrZ5YuItl',
            'username' => 'athamidn@gmail.com',
            'password' => '123456',
            'scope' => '',
            'code' => 200,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/callback',
        ],
    ]);
    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

And I received an error same with your error. After many hours I got issue :

In database at oauth_clients table this is my info :

```
2 name: Laravel Password Grant Client redirect: http://localhost
```

when I changed redirect url to this it works.
finally :

```
Route::get('/users/login', function (Request $request) {
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://payment.devenv/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => 2,
            'client_secret' => 'z8YWlJeaW0d7o7SFyPLISUxYOcO5CxjGrZ5YuItl',
            'username' => 'athamidn@gmail.com',
            'password' => '123456',
            'scope' => '',
            'code' => 200,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost'
        ],
    ]);
    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

Comment: I was having same problem for a whole day. later on when i do php artisan clear cache it get solved

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can re-create passport public and private keys stored in `/storage` folder by executing the `php artisan passport:install`. Then you can define those keys in the `.env` file and pass it with `client_id` & `client_secret`.

```
command output
Personal access client created successfully.
Client ID: 31
Client secret: xxxx
Password grant client created successfully.
Client ID: 32
Client secret: xxxx

/.env
PERSONAL_CLIENT_ID=31
PERSONAL_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxx
PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID=32
PASSWORD_CLIENT_SECRET=xxxx

POST - API parameters - /oauth/token
'client_id' => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID'),
'client_secret' => env('PASSWORD_CLIENT_SECRET')
```

This error could happen when those private and public keys are not matched properly with the already created ones.

Cheers!